# How to use accurate GDI font size?

Tags: c++, fonts, zooming, gdi

A generic question: in GDI, the type of font size is int, so it is not accurate when do zoom out/ zoom in for the text draw by GDI in the window,

Is there a simple method to use a float font size in GDI to make font size accurate?

Thanks a lot for your kindly help!

Comment: if typesetting is important, you don't want to be using the now pretty much obsolete GDI or even GDI+, you'll want to be using Direct2D, which uses a much more modern, much better text engine.

Comment: yes, thanks, I am trying to use Direct2D now, it seems can output the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

GDI text does not scale linearly, and not just because it uses only integer sizes, but also because of hinting which tries to make text look better when rendered at a resolution on the order of its stroke width.  If you double the height of a GDI font, the width may not exactly double.  GDI text was once hardware accelerated but no longer is on modern versions of Windows.  That doesn't matter much for performance because it's relatively simple and efficient, and hardware is fast.

GDI+ text will scale linearly in the sense that doubling the height will double the width (well, it's *really* close).  But text may look "fuzzier" because it uses grayscale antialiasing instead of ClearType subpixel rendering.  GDI+ text tends to be slower that GDI because more work is done in software.

DirectWrite (which runs on Direct2D) scales linearly and generally looks very good.  It's harder to write efficient Direct2D/DirectWrite code, and, depending on your requirements, you might have to drop back to GDI if you also need to print.  If you try to write DPI-aware programs, you may find yourself having to do a lot of conversions between DirectWrite's device-independent coordinates for graphics and mouse coordinates that are still device-dependant.  DirectWrite is hardware accelerated, so i'ts fast *if* you use it efficiently by caching lots of intermediate data structures.

Answer (score 1):

With `CreateFont` (and `CreateFontIndirect`) you specify the font size in pixels, so it remains accurate to the pixel regardless of zooming (within the constraints of the sizes available in the font that's selected--if you use a bitmapped font, scaling may be limited or nonexistent).

If you're using `CreatePointFont` to create the font, you specify the font size in tenths of a point, which usually works out to smaller than a pixel, so it gets rounded to the nearest pixel. If you really want to be sure you're specifying the height to the nearest pixel, however, you probably want to use `CreateFont`/`CreateFontIndirect` instead of `CreatePointFont` though.